# PhpStorm PHPUnit support

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

```
class MainTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testMain()
    {
        $stub = $this->createMock(Project\NotImplementedClass::class);

        $stub->method('doSomething')
            ->will($this->returnCallback(function ($string) {
                return strtoupper($string);
            }));

        $this->assertEquals('ABC', $stub->doSomething('abc'));
    } 
}
```

PhpStorm tells that method `doSomething` doesn't exists. I searched any plugin which can autocomplete methods. Is any plugin for this?

Comment: Where are you expecting `doSomething` to be defined? If this is just a "hello world" unit test you're creating, why not define a method yourself and stub it out?

Answer (score 1):

PHPStorm's autocomplete relies heavily on type hints. In your case - since `$this->createMock()` will return a `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject` which does not have the method it will complain.

What you can do is "overwrite" the type hint for the variable:

```
/** @var Project\NotImplementedClass|PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $stub */
$stub = $this->createMock(Project\NotImplementedClass::class);
```

or you could put the mock creation in a method with a similar `@return` docblock.

This will tell PHPStorm to look at both classes for autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

We use the [Dynamic Return Type-plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7251) to improve the type hinting of PHPUnit. It's not perfect, but is easy to set up and use. The plugin let you define return types for methods based on the value of a parameter.

Add the file `dynamicReturnTypeMeta.json` to the root of your project with the following contents:

```
{
    "methodCalls": [
        {
            "class": "\\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase",
            "method": "createMock",
            "position": 0,
            "mask": "%s|PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject"
        }
    ],
    "functionCalls": []
}
```